# Write in uitextfield without press on it

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I have created a custom cell with a textField that initially is hidden.
When I choose the cell, the textField appears and I have to press on textField to write.
This I want is when I choose the cell to write immediately in textField. This is my code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    if ( indexPath.row == 0 ){
        commentTextField.text =  [NSString stringWithFormat:commentDetailTextLabel.text];
        commentTextField.textColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
        commentTextField.hidden = NO;
        commentDetailTextLabel.hidden = YES;
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to select a UITextField?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207102/how-to-select-a-uitextfield)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `[commentTextField becomeFirstResponder];` in your `if` body.